# Sending data with QUdpSocket on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, sockets, udp

I am developing an application that periodically sends data through an UDP socket. For the moment, my code worked well until I tried to test the application with Android.

The code that I am using is:

```
m_outputSocket.writeDatagram (data, QHostAddress (robotAddress()), m_outputPort);
```

I have set the following permissions accordingly on the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
```

**Update, I also added the INTERNET permission, but it still does not work**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Running on Android, my application fails to send and receive data through UDP sockets. As a side note, the `writeDatargram` function returns -1 (indicating an error according to [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#writeDatagram)).

**Notes:**

- I am using Qt 5.6 with the Android SDK v19
- The code works on Windows and Linux, but not on Android
- The `writeDatagram` function returns -1
- I have set permissions accordingly on the AndroidManifest.xml file
- I have tried [this solution](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34111), but the application crashes while initializing.

Is there anything that can be done to get UDP working on Android with Qt?

Comment: Have you tried different android devices? And have you tried emulator as well as physical devices? I got my UDP to work without adding any permissions or making any changes at all. I just recompiled what worked in ubuntu to android target and it worked. Also what version of Qt, and what non-standard build options are you using?

Comment: Also are you using multicast or just P2P?

Comment: @LennartRolland I haven't tried the simulator yet, hopefully it will give some results. I am using standard build options, except that I set qmake to use C++11, tested Qt versions where 5.5 and 5.6.

Comment: I am using a P2P connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should add [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET)  permission too. This permission allows applications to open network sockets.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I just tried that right now, and it still does not work. Although I think it could help solve the problem, thanks!

Comment: Check is your pirmissions is still there after build process. Open `<your-build-folder>/android-build/AndroidManifest.xml` file and watch on bottom. `androiddeployqt` may modify this file for some reasons.